# implementing tabs in a fragment amidst multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, tabs, fragment

I have a sole activity for a lot of fragments. 
In one of the fragments, I must now have a few tabs inside. The ways I can think of doing it is are:

**Solution 1 - Creating a new activity just for that, and then implementing ViewPager :**

My main concern regarding that solution is this:
So far, on my Activity , I had the following flow : 
fragment 1 -> fragment 2 -> fragment -> 3 -> fragment 4 -> and on and on...

Now, suppose I have to implement those Tabs in fragment 3.

from fragment 2, I start a new activity placing a viewpager (with fragment 3 in one of the tabs and other ones in the other tabs). Then I need to be able to show fragment 4 . But since **all the fragments in the app are placed on the original activity**, it would mix up the flow or even worse. In other words cause either:

1. It would simply not show fragment 4 and so forth, because the running activity would be the one that is holding the tabs screen, while all the fragments are placed on the original activity, which would in the stack.
2. Not being able to go back from fragment 4 to the screen with the tabs, and then from 'back' from the tabs screen to fragment 2 , and then 1.

**Solution 2 - Activity for result (with view pager):**

The activity created for tabs screen could be an activity that results back to the original activity. so the flow would be like this:
fragment 2 -> new activity for result -> send result back to original activity stating that it needs to fire up fragment 4 now -> original activity opens fragment 4.

However, in that case if I go backwards from fragment 4, it would throw me back to fragment 2 instead of that tabs screen(3).

**Solution 3 - Tab Layout :**

Seems as the best solution. 
However, to use that I need `getChildFragmentManager()` , which requires api 17 and above. My api is 16.
Now, if I use `getSupportChildFragmentManager()` I would have to use fragment v4. The problem with that is that all my fragments are native, and I can't just change that fragment 3 to be v4, cause then the previous ones and the following ones would have to be v4 as well. Changing all the fragments is not an option since I have about 50 fragments.

**Another issue with solution 3** 
I've encountered , is that it crashes and prints : `Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`
I tried creating a new folder named values-v21, and created there a styles.xml for the tab layout, but that didn't help for some reason.

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: *Changing all the fragments is not an option since I have above a hundred of fragments.* - that would translate to a few keystrokes in Android Studio. The real question is why you have above one hundred fragments?

Comment: big app. and sorry , I just checked - that number is a tad exaggerated. real number is about 50 fragments(excluding different views or contentviews). Still a lot.
And frankly, I'm a bit reluctant to change all of them to v4 , so there won't be any new problems/bugs/crashes poping out.. so I'm not sure how safe would it be converting all of them to v4. But I might be wrong. Thanks

Comment: Regarding solution 1, **if** fragment 4 will be started only from the fragment 3 containing the ViewPager, I see no problem in splitting into 2 activities(1 until fragment 3 and the other continuing). Solution 2 isn't really an option. You also have solution 4 derived from solution 3: create a fragment containing the ViewPager and have the Viewpager to use only normal layouts(no nested fragments) leaving the handling of those layouts to the fragment holding the ViewPager. This will buy you time until API 16 goes into oblivion and you could refactor it to use native nested fragments.

Comment: regarding solution 1, if I split to 2 activities , there's a problem because when I want to open fragment 4, that will be committed on the original activity, which is in the back stack, so the user won't see fragment 4. Am I missing something?
Regarding the second solution you offered, I'm not sure I understood it. How would I implement ViewPager in fragment? isn't it possible on activities only? fragments can only implement Tab Layout.no?
And what would you choose of those two solutions you offered?
Thank you again.

Comment: ok so I went for the second option, which is using viewpager with layouts instead of fragments. However, it seems I have to use the PagerTabStrip to represent the page titles. Is there an alternative to it so I could see all my tabs in the screen without the need to slide sideways , and not partially like in PagerStrip?

Comment: Why aren't you using TabLayout from the design support library, it even has a convenience method to set it up with a ViewPager?

Comment: because of what I mentioned in the port regarding solution 3. 
getChildFragmentManager() requires api 17. 
Or do you mean I can implement TabLayout with layouts instead fragments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110054/discussion-between-luksprog-and-bvtp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another solution derived from solution 3. This is to keep your current navigation(fragment1->fragment2->etc) and build a fragment to hold the ViewPager with simple layouts instead of nested fragments. This way you'll avoid: navigation issues, the problematic nested apis not being present on version 16(which you plan to support) and you'll also avoid a refactoring to use the support fragment api.

And if at a later time you drop support for version 16 you could refactor each of those simple layouts in a nested fragment and use the native getChildFragmentmanager().

Comment: for some reason I keep getting this "error inflating TabLayout" crash.. 
I've added the styles.xml to values-v21 folder (solution that seems to be working for everyone)  but it doesn't help..